# Error en MYSQL : syntax error missing 'semicolon'

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una consulta y me aparece el siguiente error:

> syntax error missing 'semicolon'

Aca les dejo la consulta :

```
delimiter &&
create procedure alumnos_pagos_deudas_a_fecha (in fecha_ahora date, in dni_alum int,OUT pagado FLOAT, OUT cant_adeudado INTEGER)
 BEGIN
 select @pagado:=sum(importe_pagado)
 from cuotas c
 where c.fecha_pago<=fecha_ahora , c.dni=dni_alum and c.fecha_pago is not null;

 select @cant_adeudado:=count(*)
 from cuotas c
 where c.dni=dni_alum and c.fecha_emision<=fecha_ing and c.fecha_pago is null;

 set pagado:=@pagado ;
 set can_adeudado:=@cant:adeudado ;
END &&
delimiter ;
```

El error me lo marca en la clausula `WHERE` del primer `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

El fallo parece ser en esta fila que lo separas con una coma:

```
where c.fecha_pago<=fecha_ahora , c.dni=dni_alum and c.fecha_pago is not null;
```

debería ser con `and`

```
where c.fecha_pago<=fecha_ahora and c.dni=dni_alum and c.fecha_pago is not null;
```